# Pass state between Parent and Child components in React/Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a little confused as to how to update state between parent and child components. I know state needs to be lifted up which is why I have added it to the parent component. So I want to update the boolean value in the child component(can this be done?). I have tried as below but get the error: `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. This expression is not callable.Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.`

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hzssfh?file=Child.tsx

**Parent**

```
import React from 'react';
import Child from '../components/Child';

const Parent: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

    const toggle = () => {
        setVisible(!visible);
    };

   return (
      <button onClick={toggle}>toggle</button>
      <Child visible={visible} /> 
   )
};

export default Parent;
```

**Child**

```
import React from 'react';

interface Icomments {
visible?: boolean;
}

const Child: React.FunctionComponent<Icomments> = (props: Icomments) => {

    const handleClick = () => {
         props.visible(false);
    };

     return (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Hide</button>
     )

}

export default Child;
```

Comment: Visible is the boolean. Did you mean to pass `setVisible` to the child?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child needs the *function* that sets the state - not the state value. So you need to pass down to the Child the `setVisible` function as a prop.

```
<Child setVisible={setVisible} />
```

```
const Child = ({ setVisible }) => (
  <button onClick={() => { setVisible(false); }}>Hide</button>
);
```

Comment: That gives an error: `Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | undefined'. Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'true'.`

Comment: It sounds like you're still mixing up the state vs the state setter - make sure you pass down and reference only the *state setter* (the `setVisible`), not the state, which you don't care about.

Comment: I do not think you have copied the code from my answer correctly - it does not produce the error you describe.

Comment: But I am using Typescript

Comment: Yes, I know - and passing down the state setter properly and calling it with `false` does not produce the error. The error would only occur if you're still mixing up the state and the state setter, eg if you're doing `<Child setVisible={visible} />` instead. (pass down the state setter, not the state)

Comment: Do you not think it is something to do with the type in the child component?

Comment: Yes, your interface should match up as well - again, you need to pass down the *state setter alone*, not the state, and reference that state setter (the `Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>`) everywhere it's used - *not* the state, the boolean, which you don't care about.

Comment: Hi so I have updated the question with a stackblitz example. It works but as you can see its complaining about the setVisible in the child component

Comment: You are *still* telling TypeScript that you're passing down the boolean, rather than the state setter: `setVisible?: boolean;` Pass down and reference *everywhere* the state setter instead of the state. The state setter can be either `(newVisible: boolean) => void` or `Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>`

Comment: Could you update the stackblitz? to what you mean?

Comment: Change `const Child: React.FunctionComponent<Icomments> = (props: Icomments)` to `const Child = ({ setVisible }: { setVisible: (newVisible: boolean) => void })` to indicate that you want to pass down the state setter instead of the state. Or you can use `Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>` instead of `(newVisible: boolean) => void`, it's up to you.

Comment: Again, you don't care about the state at all, so the `Icomments {
setVisible?: boolean;
}` doesn't make sense - reference only the state setter, not the boolean.

Comment: Thats we got there

Comment: Just a quick one, what if I wanted to pass the state and not the setter for example `visible` is it the same concept?

Comment: For the most part, just make sure everything relating to the props is referencing the state value rather than the state setter. `<Child visible={visible}` and `const Child = ({ visible }: { visible: boolean }) =>`